# sequelize hasOne() allowing duplicate value in child/foreign table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have been digging too hard into sequelize association, and I have noticed that hasOne() association allows duplicate records in the foreign/child table. Technically hasOne() is used to assign a one-to-one relationship then why it's allowing duplicate records in a foreign table?

Let me explain to you in-depth, I have two tables user and userProfile, technically user should have only one profile field/row in userProfile table. but when I try to add another record, it's allowing and adding it to the profile table. It means it duplicates it, which should not happen, Can anyone explain why?

This is how I am assigning it,

```
static associate(models) {
      User.hasOne(models.Profile, {foreignKey: 'id', sourceKey:'id'});
    }
static associate(models) {
      Profile.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'id'});
    }
```

what I have tried till now is, to add a unique key constraint to the Profile table or you can say manually assign it during migration, but if doing it in that then why do I need an hasOne() association?

This is how i managed it,

```
 id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userId: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id',
        },
        unique: true,
      },
      profile: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
```

can anyone explain WHY DO I NEED AN hasOne() ASSOCIATION if it's not defining a unique key on the foreign key column?